# How to Paginate a Pop Up Component in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, pagination

I am trying to Paginate this Pop up. Can anyone tell me how I can do this using a reusable **Paginate** Component.

```
<EntityPopup
      title={constants.SELECT_SUPPLIER_HEADER}
      isOpened={this.state.isSupplierPopupOpen}
      onModalClose={this.closeSupplierPopup}
      onSelect={this.selectSupplier}
      entity={this.props.suppliers}
      columns={constants.SUPPLIER_MODAL_COLUMN_NAMES}
      emptyTableMessage={constants.NO_SUPPLIERS_MESSAGE}
    />
```

Comment: an advice, try to be more specific for.e.g seems like the problem is just how to paginate and may not have anything to do with a popup also what kind of code have you written for the actual pagination stuff ?

Comment: @harshitpthk, the issue as I mentioned is for Pagination inside the Pop up window and not just Pagination. It's like a Search Box open a Pop up which contains list of items to be selected, I just want to add Pagination in that pop up.

Answer (score 0):

I use [react-paginate](https://github.com/AdeleD/react-paginate). It's pretty flexible. I applied bootstrap classes to make it look like the bootstrap paginator; and I'm pretty sure it's flexible enough to use with any framework.

Here's an example of what I did.

```
<ReactPaginate
  containerClassName="pagination"
  pageClassName="page-item"
  pageLinkClassName="page-link"
  previousClassName="page-item"
  previousLinkClassName="page-link"
  nextClassName="page-item"
  nextLinkClassName="page-link"
  breakClassName="page-item"
  breakLinkClassName="page-link"
  activeClassName="active"
/>
```